# Power App Daily Operation - slow performance using power automate

Tags: licensing, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-modeldriven

As we read a lot of different types of licenses couldn't understand actual daily limit of license that my company have and **do it have difference if of number of daily operation based on license type**?

[image]

This is license that currently have - can we agree that daily operation is same [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/api-request-limits-allocations)

[image]

It's related in my case especially for Power Automate - because when the system reach daily limit automatically scale to very slow close to zero execution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enforcement of limitations should be coming up soon.
There are some ways to make your flows much more efficient in api calls, which may be more elegant than spreading one’s workflows across several accounts and/or set-ups.

If anyone runs into call limits, throttling, or other performance issues when creating, updating, or deleting many items in SharePoint, Excel, or SQL, then you may find these 50-1000x more efficient batch templates useful…

Sharepoint
Update, Create, & Upsert- https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/Batch-Update-Create-and-Upsert-SharePoint-Lists/td-p/1365410
Create- https://www.tachytelic.net/2021/06/power-automate-flow-batch-create-sharepoint-list-items/?amp
Delete- https://www.tachytelic.net/2021/06/power-automate-delete-sharepoint-items/

Excel
Create & Update- https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/Excel-Batch-Create-Update-and-Upsert/td-p/1624706
Delete- https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/Excel-Batch-Delete/td-p/1634375

SQL
Use stored procedures:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-power-automate-inserting-data-sql-db-stored-procedure-wijaya
Or this batch template:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/SQL-Batch-Create-Read-Update-and-Delete/td-p/1715338

Also in many cases you can use two Filter arrays, one for true/yes, one for false/no instead of conditionals within an Apply to each.

Finally, make sure you are using trigger conditions for flows that only need to run in a sub-set of cases in which an action is performed
https://youtu.be/PVc-M9dFURs